# Is it possible to make shutdown impossible?

Tags: 18.04

I am running some Linux boxes in the field and long story short, I would simply like to make it impossible to shutdown any of the boxes. Is this possible?

Comment: Impossible for *whom*?

Comment: Everyone, even root

Comment: Just the "`shutdown`" command? What about `/sbin/halt`? What about tripping over the power cord? No matter what wall you build with `root`, `root` can get around it.

Comment: To do it properly, you must recompile systemd to omit all of systemctl's shutdown options. Those /sbin commands are simply links to systemctl.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a alias for `shutdown`
2. Edit sudoers and negate the allow with a exclamation mark, `!SHUTDOWN` .

Edit:  `/etc/sudoers`

Add these lines to Command Aliases section.

```
Cmnd_Alias     SHUTDOWN = /sbin/shutdown,/sbin/reboot,/sbin/halt,/sbin/poweroff

# User privilege specification
root   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL, !SHUTDOWN

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%developers  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL,  !SHUTDOWN
```

Ref.: https://www.tecmint.com/disable-shutdown-and-reboot-commands-in-linux/

Comment: Please upvote my answer then :-)

Comment: I did, just don't have enough karma for it to matter.